# How can I make only one instance of an application receive each AMQP topic message (consumer group behaviour)

Tags: apache-camel, amqp, activemq-artemis

I am using [Apache Camel's AMQP](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/amqp-component.html) component to listen to messages from an ActiveMQ Artemis topic.

This application is run on Kubernetes with two replicas.

I've configured a durable subscription with a unique clientId per pod and a common subscription name:

```xml
<route autoStartup=true" id="myRoute">
    <from id="_amqp_topic" uri="amqp:topic:xxx?connectionFactory=#amqpCF&amp;disableReplyTo=true&amp;transacted=false&amp;subscriptionDurable=true&amp;clientId={{container-id}}&amp;durableSubscriptionName=eventSubscription"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Received event: ${body}"/>
    ...
</route>
```

The problem is both pods receive the message, when only one of them should. I'm trying to achieve something similar to [Kafka's consumer groups](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_consumer_group_example.htm), where only one member of the group receives each message.

Comment: A queue should fit your requirements better than a topic. Why are you using a topic?

Comment: Because multiple applications will listen from that topic.

Comment: Why is it you think two different durable topic subscribers won't get the same message?  Please clarify as it currently seems that there is not issue in what the broker is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **only one** subscriber to receive the message then the subscribers must *share* the same subscription. Therefore, you need to:

- set `subscriptionShared=true` in your `_amqp_topic` `uri`
- use the *same* client ID (i.e. don't use `{{container-id}}`)

For example:

```xml
<route autoStartup=true" id="myRoute">
    <from id="_amqp_topic" uri="amqp:topic:xxx?connectionFactory=#amqpCF&amp;disableReplyTo=true&amp;transacted=false&amp;subscriptionDurable=true&amp;clientId=myClientID&amp;durableSubscriptionName=eventSubscription&amp;subscriptionShared=true"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Received event: ${body}"/>
    ...
</route>
```

Another option would simply to use a **queue** instead of a topic, e.g.:

```xml
<route autoStartup=true" id="myRoute">
    <from id="_amqp_queue" uri="amqp:queue:xxx?connectionFactory=#amqpCF&amp;disableReplyTo=true&amp;transacted=false"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Received event: ${body}"/>
    ...
</route>
```

Comment: I configured the amqp listener as indicated. The first pod starts ok but the second one shows this error: `o.a.c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer ERROR - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'xxx' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Received error from remote peer without description [condition = amqp:invalid-field] `

Comment: Do you see any exceptions on the broker?

Comment: At the moment I can't access the broker logs. I'm accepting the answer since it seems correct acording to the docs. Thanks for your help.